# Avoid duplicate insert to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following code that inserts an entity with random generated value "hawb" as one of the column. My idea was since the **hawb** is a **unique** column in the table, the try-catch block will catch the exception when duplicate value is being inserted. The workflow works fine until I start testing it and get some weird error.

```
[Code]
hawb = "0402135505536";
while (!uniqueHawb)  //insert new hawb
{
    //hawb = $"{DateTime.Now:MMddHHmmss}{RandomHelper.GetRandomNumber(0, 999):000}";

    var entity = new HawbAsset { HAWB = hawb, HawbStatus = "Allocated", AllocatedDateTime = DateTime.Now, AllocationReference = reference };

    try
    {
        _repository.Insert(entity);
        uniqueHawb = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ;
    }
    hawb = $"{DateTime.Now:MMddHHmmss}{RandomHelper.GetRandomNumber(0, 999):000}";
}

[Model]
    public class HawbAsset : BaseEntity
    {
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        [StringLength(15)]
        public string HAWB { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string HawbStatus { get; set; }

        public DateTime? AllocatedDateTime { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string AllocationReference { get; set; }

        public DateTime? ConfirmedUsageDateTime { get; set; }

        public DateTime? RecycledDateTime { get; set; }

        public string Owner { get; set; }
    }
```

I have hardcoded a duplicate value 0402135505536 so it will catch the "Duplicate Key Exception" the first time, which is expected. However, when the hawb been randomly generated, and I have make sure the value is different, it still catches the same "Duplicate Key Exception". Can anyone tell me what is going on and how to achieve my goal? Thanks!

Comment: Have you confirmed that when generating hawb that the same value is not being generated for some reason? Can you add Console.Writeline(hawb.toString()) to your catch block and confirm that first?

Comment: Yes i have confirmed the hawb value has been updated and the new entity is different.

Comment: Any other unique constraints on the table?

Comment: The only unique is hawb. I will add the model in my post.

Comment: Why are you generating a random number at all for a KEY?

Comment: well, that is the requirement.

Comment: I don't see why my question gets a negative. It is a valid question with codes presenting, and I have tried to debug it myself.

Comment: You say that it's a requirement...I'm just going to throw this out there...just in case:  SQL Server doesn't require that you set a value yourself (it can be done automatically).

Comment: Someone probably didn't like your approach without realizing that developers have to start somewhere and many are still in the early learning stages with a technology like EF, but IMO a downvote should reflect the quality of the question, not the quality of code.  Your question was fine. As far as unique key requirements go, the typical approach is to leverage a GUID (with the DB taking care of setting it), Snowflake or other reasonably reliable pattern before rolling your own, though depending on the solution, collision risks are still there, and this issue can still trip up a developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is because you tried inserting one entity with the duplicate ID and that failed. On the retry, you are creating a 2nd entity and trying to insert that.. The first entity is still associated to the context and will still try to save. You need to detach it from the context before saving the new replacement, or update the existing entity.  (below)

```
hawb = "0402135505536";
var entity = new HawbAsset { HAWB = hawb, HawbStatus = "Allocated", AllocatedDateTime = DateTime.Now, AllocationReference = reference };
while (!uniqueHawb)  //insert new hawb
{
    //hawb = $"{DateTime.Now:MMddHHmmss}{RandomHelper.GetRandomNumber(0, 999):000}";

    try
    {
        _repository.Insert(entity);
        uniqueHawb = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ;
    }
    entity.HAWB = $"{DateTime.Now:MMddHHmmss}{RandomHelper.GetRandomNumber(0, 999):000}";
}
```

To detach an entity you need to use `context.Entity(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;`  which would need to operate through your repository boundary.

Ideally though, it would be better to check the uniqueness of the HAWB before attempting the insert, but still handling the exception for those very, very rare cases that an entry gets saved between the check and the save:

```
int retryCount = 0
while (retryCount < 5)
{
  try
  {
    bool isUnique = false;
    string hawb = null;
    while(!isUnique)
    { 
      hawb = generateHawb();
      isUnique = context.HawbAssets.Any(x => x.HAWB == hawb);
    }
    entity.HAWB = hawb; // this hawb should be unique, so set and insert.
    _repository.Insert(entity);
  }
  catch(UpdateException)
  {
  // log that this has happened, check inner exception for duplicate key and retry, though limit retry attempts if there are deeper issues that might lock up the system in a retry loop.
    retryCount++;
  }
}
```

Comment: I solved my problem with detaching the entity, thanks Steve!

Comment: this is why you use short-lived contexts

Answer (score 1):

Its 1 line of extra code to check if the entity exists.  Do that first and dont rely on error handling to do the work:

```
if ( _repository.HAWBAssets.FirstOrDefault(i => i.HAWB == hawb)== null)
    {
     _repository.Insert(entity);
        uniqueHawb = true;
    }
```

Comment: The reason being it is still possible (unlikely) for the hawb to be generated as duplicate between the time of checking and inserting. But it is a valid point, I should still do a check prior to avoid duplicate at first.

Comment: I have also added the quick check as suggested, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use nanoseconds to make big distance between records to reduce possibility of duplication

```
entity.HAWB = $"{DateTime.Now.Ticks}";
// 636898603227146583
```

`DateTime.Ticks` resolution is 100 nanoseconds

Comment: I need to keep the format due to the requirement, or that would be the easiest solution  :(